# NoneType in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get some rating data from [Tripadvisor](http://'http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g186338-London_England-Hotels.html') but as i was trying to fetch the data i was getting

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Can anybody help me figuring out where am i going wrong , sorry i am very new to python.

Here is my sample code

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g186338-London_England-Hotels.html')
data = r.text        
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for rate in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"rating"}):
               print (rate.img['alt'])
```

The output to this looks like:

```
4.5 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars 4 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars 4 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars
4.5 of 5 stars Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-52-7460e8bfcb82>", line 3, in <module>
    print (rate.img['alt'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `rate.img is None`...

Comment: It means there is no `<img/>` tag under at least one of your `rate` divs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all your `<div class="rating">` tags have an `<img />` tag, so `rate.img` is `None`.

Those divs look like this instead:

```html
<div class="rating">
  <span class="rate">4.5 out of 5, </span>
  <em>2,294 Reviews</em>
  <br/>
  <div class="posted">Last reviewed 25 Sep 2015</div>
</div>
```

You can either test for this:

```
if rate.img is not None:
    # ...
```

or select only images under the `div.rating` tags with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for img in soup.select('div.rating img[alt]'):
```

The selector here picks out `<img/>` tags with an `alt` attribute, nested inside a `<div class="rating">` tag.

Comment: Ahh i missed that thanks, not None condition helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It means that not all `div`s with a class of `rating` have images with an `alt` attribute. You should handle this appropriately - to ignore such cases, just wrap your `print (rate.img['alt'])` in a try, except block, or check to see if `rate.img` is `None` first.

First option:

```
try:
    print(rate.img['alt'])
except TypeError:
    print('Rating error')
```

Second option:

```
for rate in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"rating"}):
    if rate.img is not None:
        print (rate.img['alt'])
```

The first option follows [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission), a common Python coding style, whereas the second follows [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) (Look before you leap). In this case, I would suggest the second.

Comment: Thanks for the response, indeed it was due to some None cases.